# Error 1118: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com este erro ao adicionar tabelas a minha base de dados.
Alguém me saber ajudar neste situação?
Pois os dados já estão como Barracuda.

Os campos que estou a adicionar são do Tipo: Text, Varchar(20), Longblob.

Comment: Pelo jeito que falou sua tabela tem realmente MUITOS campos. Depois de alterar os tipos das colunas, se o erro persistir, talvez valha a pena é separar em mais de uma tabela os seus dados. Se são tantos campos assim, provavelmente você não vai fazer uma consulta que envolva todos esses dados mesmo, pode até conseguir separar deixando juntos os campos que são buscados juntos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base em [Row size too large error in mysql create table query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13283432), no SO, texto tradução:

> O tamanho total de todos os campos da tabela é mais do que o limite, 65535, é por isso que você está recebendo este erro.
>   Você deve usar o tipo de texto em vez de varchar para cadeias longas. Substituir todos varchar (8000) com o texto, e ele deve funcionar. 
>   Ou, melhor ainda, usar tipos de dados apropriados, em vez de os "muito grande". Você realmente não precisa de 8000 caracteres para armazenar moeda, não é?

Tente seguir essa orientação e nos de um feedback, posteriormente, eu mesmo nunca passei por isso, mas, sempre tem a primeira vez.

Comment: e tenho de alterar tudo o que tem varchar para text..

Comment: Boa pergunta @ChrisAdler, eu faria o seguinte criaria uma tabela teste e ia mudando para ver o que acontece, é o único jeito de você realmente tirar a sua dúvida, e com isso postar aqui o que aconteceu!

Comment: Criar uma tabela tambem com muitos dados?
Mas em vez de ser varchar ser text correcto?

Comment: Isso, @ChrisAdler, como teste ... depois se vai observando o comportamento

Comment: Pronto testei uma tabela a parte substituir todos os varchar por text. Até ver resultou.

Comment: Deu certo @ChrisAdler ???

Comment: Sim deu.. penso que tava a dar erro por causa do barracuda